# Changing text in automated email sent from TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

**Background**

After submitting an application to the Apple Developer Center I added some test users to Test Flight. At this point I used the option to send invites to the test users.

Inside the email that is sent to the test users is some text. I noticed that one of the words in the text is spelled wrong. I have searched through the Apple Developer Center but cannot find where this text is being pulled in from.

**Example**

It says,

> By Company Name *Corperation* for IOS.

Corporation is spelled wrong.

[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know where this text comes from and how to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After speaking to Apple support they informed me this issue was something on their backend. In other words when the account was setup the Apple team does some data entry on the backend to prepare the account as an organization or a business account. In this case the representative entering the data misspelled Corporation by spelling it,

> Corperation

To fix this,

I called into Apple developer support and spoke to a representative. They found the problem and informed me the Agent on the developer account must call in to request the change formally. I notified the Agent and had him call in. Once they called in and gave the ticket number, they requested the change to be made. The agent was informed it would take up to 24 hours for the changes to be made.

Please also be away this issue must be escalated to a higher tier technician from Apple support. So make sure to get a ticket number and have access to the Agent on the developer account. They will have to request the change.